# Floating div with floating li, how do I center the text in the LI

Tags: html, css

I have to implement the following, simple as it may seem, design sample in HTML/CSS but I can't seem to get the text with the two pipes to center align on the page. [Left Line, Text and Right Line in a centered position with text almost in the middle of the lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miNV1.jpg)

Here is the CSS code that I currently have:

```
#nav {
float: right;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS","Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 6.5em;
margin: 0px 0 10px;
/****************IE6****************/
padding-top: 0em;
}
#nav ul {
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}
ul, ol, dl, li, dt, dd, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, body, html, p, blockquote, fieldset, input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul, ol {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
#nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background:url(pipe.png) no-repeat 100% 50%;
}
#nav ul li:last-child
{
    background: none;
}
#nav li  {
    color: #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 5px;
}


/*End hide*/
/*Mac IE 5*/
* html #nav li:first-child { border-left: 0; }
```

And this is my HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            &nbsp;
        </li>
        <li> 
            LYNXX
        </li>
        <li>
        &nbsp;
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

1. Adding an outer div and aligning that center, that did nothing to the inner div
2. I've tried using three div's instead and floating all left, but could still not align the text in the middle of the "pipes"/lines

I've tried a lot more, but after the 5 hours that I've already spent on it, I can't remember what I did and what I didn't do anymore.

This should be IE 7,8,9 and all other latest browsers ready.

If anyone can help me with this I'll be VERY grateful.

Thanks
Anina

Comment: Why use float? Create a div container, put inside of it another three divs and play with position: absolute; and top left.

Comment: You mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Dqz3R/

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<ul>
 <li><span>Text goes here</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
 background: #000;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 padding: 30px 100px;
}
ul li span {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 10px 50px;
 border-width: 0 1px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MKf4B/

That's a simple implementation

Comment: Hi XFortyFourx, thanks for your response, this solution worked perfectly until I added more characters to the text.  Then it wrapped the text to the next line, which I don't want.  I'm going to use this solution in a dynamic scenario where the text can be x-amount of characters (it will never wrap to the next line) but the spacing between the pipe and the text will always be the same distance away.  So the solution works well if the characters are always the same, but when did that ever happen, any idea how I can get this to work with a dynamic scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using li's to hold the pipes?

I think this may be more suitable

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text">
        Text goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

With these styles

```
    .container {
        width: 500px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .text {
        width: 250px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .text:before {
        content: "|";
    }

    .text:after {
        content: "|";
    }
```

I'm assuming you understand how to use this on li's, if that's what you really need.

Comment: This did not do the trick, since IE7 can't see the content: "|" part of the css.  Also I've tried this solution before but for some reason the text always appear in the upper part of the black background.  Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: Apologies, I was unaware that IE7 doesn't support the pseudo class. I'm not sure what you mean by your question here though, perhaps you just need to adjust the margin and/or padding on the interior container to position it exactly where you want it?